# Why is pgAdmin caching my username in a clean install of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to remove and do a clean install of PostgreSQL (Windows). I uninstall it, delete the `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL` folder and re-install it from the installer.

When I launch pgAdmin, I enter my newly-created master password and then try to log into the default PostgreSQL 13 server. At this point it prompts me for a password for my *old* username 'kirkbross' instead of (what I expected in a clean install) the default 'postres' user. When I use psql to check users, it's as expected... just the postgres user.

Why is pgAdmin caching my username? I was able to go into properties and change the username, but I'm just wondering how it propagated across a new install.

```
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a user name, then it tries to log you on with the user name which has the same spelling as your OS user name does.  This is not a cache, it is just a default behavior (of the client, not the server).